# Reactjs and react-redux, fetch data from database before rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reselect

i have the next piece of code that uses react, react-redux , and will have a firebase call to get some objects from the server:

```
const GroupsPage = ({groups}) => (
  <div className='groups-page'>

      <div className='groups'>
      {
                    groups.map(({id,...otherGroupProps}) => (
                        <GroupItem key={id} id={id}{...otherGroupProps}/>
                    ))
                }
      </div>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  groups: selectGroups
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupsPage);
```

My question is the following, before rendering this component , more exactly, the map statement, i want to fetch some items from firebase, because by default groups = [], so
how should i organize my code so that first i make the call and use mapDispatchToProps to send the fetched data to the state, and only after that i render the groups.map part?

Comment: You can define and dispatch an action that fetches the data from its's parent component. or you can also add useEffect to the GroupsPage component to call and dispatch the action only once .

Comment: @PrakashS , could you please help me with an example?

Comment: Are you using redux toolkit ?

Comment: here is an example since redux-toolkit is the recommended way going forward.https://codesandbox.io/s/prakash-redux-toolkit-example-9j901